# In Laravel Eloquent, how to check for multiple relationship existence in one "has"?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So, in order to check the existence of a relationship on a model, we use the `has` function on the relationship like `model1->has('relationship1')`.

While it is possible to supply the `model1->with()` function with an array of relations to eager load them all, both `has` and `whereHas` functions do not accept arrays as parameters. How to check for the existence of multiple relationships?

Right now, I am running multiple `has` functions on the same model (The relations are not nested):

```
model1->has('relationship1')
      ->has('relationship2')
      ->has('relationship3')
```

But that is tedious and error-prone. Solution anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There unfortunately isn't a way to pass an array of relationships to `has()` or `whereHas()`, but you can use a `QueryScope` instead. On your `Model`, define the following:

```
public function scopeCheckRelationships($query){
  return $query->has("relationship1")->has("relationship2")->has("relationship3");
}
```

Then, when querying your `Model` in a `Controller`, simply run:

```
$result = Model::checkRelationships()->get();
```

The function name to use a `Scope` is the name of the function, minus the word `scope`, so `scopeCheckRelationships()` is used as `checkRelationships()`.

Also, it's actually possible to pass the relationships you want to query as a param:

```
public function scopeCheckRelationships($query, $relationships = []){
  foreach($relationships AS $relationship){
    $query->has($relationship);
    // Might need to be `$query = $query->has(...);`, but I don't think so.
  }
  return $query;
}

...

$result = Model::checkRelationships(["relationship1", "relationship2", "relationship3"])->get();
```

In case you need this to be dynamic.

Here's the documentation for Query Scopes if you need more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: Rather disappointing. I think the team should make a feature for that. Thanks though.

Comment: I hear you. Laravel is open source, so you may be able to suggest that this be implemented in a future version, or, if you're really savvy, you can modify the code yourself and do a pull request. Might be a little complicated though, but might also be really simple. Hard to say.